# SQL Server Overlapping / Concurrent Events Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have teammates that can take multiple concurrent chats at a time. The goal is to find all the instances of overlapping chats and then aggregate the concurrency as an average so we can see for example, teammate A averages 1.4 simultaneous chats and teammate B averages 2.2.

The below script captures many overlapping / concurrent chats but it's not 100% effective at capturing all overlaps correctly.

```
SELECT x2.* 
    , sum(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY TeammateID,ChatDate ORDER BY   ChatDate, event_time) AS ConcurrentChats
    FROM ( SELECT x.*
           FROM (
              SELECT ct.ChatID, 
                     ct.ChatDate, 
                     ct.ChatChannel, 
                     ct.TeammateID, 
                     ct.ChatQueue, 
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime, ct.ChatDate) AS                   First_Response_Date, 
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime + ct.HandlingTime, ct.ChatDate) AS Chat_End_Date, 
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime, ct.ChatDate) AS    event_time,
                     1 AS flag
              FROM   server.db.chat AS ct
                     INNER JOIN server.db.Teammates AS da ON ct.TeammateID = da.TeammateID
              WHERE  ct.IsAbandoned = 0
                     AND DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime, ct.ChatDate) IS NOT NULL
                                       and ct.ChatDate >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,DATEADD(qq,-1,GETDATE())), 0)
           UNION 
               SELECT ct.ChatID, 
                     ct.ChatDate, 
                     ct.ChatChannel, 
                     ct.TeammateID, 
                     ct.ChatQueue, 
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime, ct.ChatDate) AS                   First_Response_Date, 
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime + ct.HandlingTime, ct.ChatDate) AS Chat_End_Date,                  
                     DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime + ct.HandlingTime, ct.ChatDate) AS                   event_time, 
                     -1 AS flag
              FROM   server.db.chat AS ct
                     INNER JOIN server.db.Teammates AS da ON ct.TeammateID = da.TeammateID
              WHERE  ct.IsAbandoned = 0
                     AND DATEADD(ss, ct.QueueTime, ct.ChatDate) IS NOT NULL
                                       and ct.ChatDate >= DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq,0,DATEADD(qq,-1,GETDATE())), 0)
                 ) x    
     ) x2
    WHERE 1 = 1
    ORDER BY TeammateID, ChatDate, event_time
```

The following output occurs. A chat is not supposed to subtract from concurrency until it has ended so that it gives proper credit for overlapping events. If you look at the output, you will see that chat 380249 is subtracted from the total even though chat 380269 was happening simultaneously from ~11:26 to ~11:41.

```
ChatID  ChatDate    ChatChannel TeammateID  Queue   First_Response_Date Chat_End_Date event_time flag ConcurrentChats
380200  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   10:36:11 AM    10:48:16 AM  10:36:11 AM     1       1
380200  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   10:36:11 AM    10:48:16 AM  10:48:16 AM    -1       0
380249  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:13:05 AM    11:41:17 AM  11:13:05 AM     1       1
380249  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:13:05 AM    11:41:17 AM  11:41:17 AM    -1       0
380269  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:26:07 AM    11:42:12 AM  11:26:07 AM     1       1
380269  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:26:07 AM    11:42:12 AM  11:42:12 AM    -1       0
```

The output should look more like this:

```
ChatID  ChatDate    ChatChannel TeammateID  Queue   First_Response_Date Chat_End_Date event_time flag ConcurrentChats
    380200  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   10:36:11 AM    10:48:16 AM  10:36:11 AM     1       1
    380200  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   10:36:11 AM    10:48:16 AM  10:48:16 AM    -1       0
    380249  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:13:05 AM    11:41:17 AM  11:13:05 AM     1       1
    380269  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:26:07 AM    11:42:12 AM  11:26:07 AM     1       2
    380249  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:13:05 AM    11:41:17 AM  11:41:17 AM    -1       0
    380269  7/1/2020    Mobile       1          Outerwear   11:26:07 AM    11:42:12 AM  11:42:12 AM    -1       0
```

Comment: Did you alter the output? The ordering doesn't appear to match the query.

Comment: @shawnt00, the first output is not altered. The second one I altered the order of the results.

Comment: The first one isn't by order of `event_time`. How is that possible?

Comment: The first one is by order of event_time. Notice that the event time is the start time in the first part of the query and event_time is the chat end time in the Union part of the query.

Comment: I have read the query. The `event_time` column values are not in ascending order as they should be per `order by`. Does that suggest that their is a date component being stripped out?

Comment: Maybe it's that I have it ordered by ChatDate and event_time? The Time from the ChatDate column is being stripped out, I just noticed.

Comment: Those dates are all the same though.